# Is there any plugin to show number of clicks on the link?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, widgets

I have a post having different links. I have to show number of clicks on each link.
Is there any link to show number of clicks on the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP-Click-Track

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-click-track/

> The click tracker works in 2 modes:
>
> 1. Scans posts and rewrites them to include a tracking element
> 2. Enables users to create stand alone trackable links that can be embedded in posts or offsite.

Comment: Can I show count on post?

Comment: As it's storing the number of clicks per link, yes you can. If there's no built in functionality, you can write some code to query the database